# .Net Core WebAPI , Unable to post data with POSTMAN , error - 415 Unsupported MediaType

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-mvc, postman

I am testing my first .net Core WebAPI with Postman

> unknown media type error is occurring.

What am I missing?

[image: This is postman rest client]

This is my posting object

```
public class Country
{
    [Key]
    public int CountryID { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
    public string CountryShortName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

This is the webapi controller

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostCountry([FromBody] Country country)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    _context.Country.Add(country);
    try
    {
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateException)
    {
        if (CountryExists(country.CountryID))
        {
            return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status409Conflict);
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    return CreatedAtAction("GetCountry", new { id = country.CountryID }, country);
}
```

Comment: Can you post what's in the "Headers" tab? Try setting the Content-Type to application/json

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You're not sending the `Content-Type` header. Choose `JSON (application/json)` in the dropdown near the mouse pointer on your first screenshot:
[image: Like this]

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I was using api in the route.

Comment: To anyone else who's struggling with this answer, counter-intuitively rather than specifying the content type, then supplying form data, you need to select raw. At this point the new encoding type drop-list appears and you can select JSON. IMHO Poor UI design, but once you know, you know.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me (I was using api in the route)

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Countries")]
public class CountriesController : Controller
{
    // POST: api/Countries
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostCountry([FromBody] Country country)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        _context.Country.Add(country);
        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException)
        {
            if (CountryExists(country.CountryID))
            {
                return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status409Conflict);
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return CreatedAtAction("GetCountry", new { id = country.CountryID }, country);
    }
}
```

[image]